# How to use CombBox Value in If Statment in VBA excel?

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

[image]

I need to update on exist ticket number on VBA in excel

However, I tried many times to bring the data from the sheet to comboBox of Ticket number from "A2" to lastRow Added, but it tell me its wrong syntax.

How to take the value of ComboBox
? how to insert it in IF statement?
please help me to make the following condition

1. get the ticket number from **Tickets** sheet
2. write the update value from combBox **Close by** and **Ticket Status** to both **Ticket** Sheet and remove them from **PendingTickets** sheet if the Ticket status is Solved or Closed

the code of test If the Ticket Status is Pending or On Progress

```
Dim Ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim openOn As Date


'Declare openBy to date Now function'
openOn = Now()
'set format function on time var'
openTimeAmPM = Format(openOn, "m.d.yy h:mm AM/PM")


 'copy ticket data to Pending tickst sheet if the ticket status is Pending or On progress'
  '  If SieraForum.CombTicketStatus.Value = "Pending" Or "On Progress" Then
        Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = lastRow
        Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 2).Value = SieraForum.txtTicketName.Value
        
        ElseIf SieraForum.ErrorOption = True Then
         Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = "Error"
        ElseIf SieraForum.OrderOption = True Then
         Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 3).Value = "Order"
        
            Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 4).Value = SieraForum.CombSeverity.Value
            Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 5).Value = SieraForum.CombLocation.Value
            Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 6).Value = SieraForum.txtTicketDetails.Value
            Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 7).Value = SieraForum.CombOpenBy.Value
            Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 8).Value = SieraForum.CombCloseBy.Value
            Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 9).Value = SieraForum.CombTicketStatus.Value
            Sheets("PendingTickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 10).Value = openTimeAmPM
    
    Else
         MsgBox "The Ticket is Added Successfully"
    End If
```

the Code of Save Button on Tap **Update Ticket**

```
    Private Sub btnSave2_Click()
 
    'declare close on date function'
     Dim closeOn As Date
     
     ' set format function on time var'
     closeOn = Now()
     closeTimeAmPM = Format(openOn, "m.d.yy h:mm AM/PM")
    
     
    'To enter new line'
    lastRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Sheets("Tickets").Range("A:A"))
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 1).Value = lastRow
     
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 8).Value = SieraForum.CombCloseBy.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 9).Value = SieraForum.CombTicketStatus2.Value
    'write the update statement'
    'Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 12).Value = "Update Statement > " + SieraForum.txtTicketUpdate.Value
    Sheets("Tickets").Cells(lastRow + 1, 11).Value = closeTimeAmPM
            
    'Clear the data from the form'
    SieraForum.CombTicketNum.Value = ""
    SieraForum.CombCloseBy = ""
    SieraForum.CombTicketStatus2 = ""
    SieraForum.txtTicketUpdate.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The first `If` is commented out.  The Syntax Error is caused by having `ElseIf`, `Else` and `End If` without a matching `If`.